# Pushing code to Azure DevOps using SSH on WSL fails

Tags: git, ssh, azure-devops, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using WSL2 on Windows10 with Ubuntu. I have set up SSH successfully, i.e. the IT department has defined a firewall rule for port 22. However for pushing code to an empty DevOps Repo I get issues, if I do

```
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

it asks for my password

```
Password for 'https://organisationname@dev.azure.com'
```

however it should not ask me for a password (I would not even know it) when SSH is defined. I did also a first commit locally, so there is definitely code to be pushed. It seems as if it would not use my SSH key for the push command. So the cloning of another remote repo was successful:

```
git clone git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/COMPANY-IT/COMPANY%20IT/COMPANY%20IT
```

so I tried for my local code (I emptied the remote repo in the meanwhile)

```
git push --set-upstream git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/COMPANY-IT/COMPANY%20IT/COMPANY%20IT
```

but it results in

```
error: src refspec git@ssh.dev.azure.com does not match any
```

How can I push code to my remote repo? Why do I need to specify for the clone command the ssh part? the origin has been defined before with

```
git remote add origin ...
```

Comment: `-set-upstream` is intended to set the remote name, not the full URL - it's complaining because you're specifying an URL instead of the ref of the upstream. Can you please run `git remote show origin` and include the result in your question, so that we can see how it's set up? (obviously, removing any customer specific data)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that my account had insufficient permissions. After the admin changed them

```
git push -u origin --all
```

worked immediately. This command returns the hint that access rights might be missing. I see that I also missed the branch in one of my commands

```
git push --set-upstream master
```

would be correct

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it looks like the remote is currently an HTTPS remote.  To change it to a new SSH remote, you can write this:

```
$ git remote set-url origin git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/COMPANY-IT/COMPANY%20IT/COMPANY%20IT
```

That should make your normal operations succeed.